# getting the text value from label to see if it's nil or not?

Tags: objective-c

What i'm doing is basically on button clicking, i'm checking to see if textfield is empty or not. 
So, i have three textfield as below and other label named alarmLb which will display message when textfield is empty.

```
- (IBAction)addBtn:(id)sender {
// **checking the textfield**
if (self.firstNameTxt.text != nil &&
   self.lastNameTxt.text != nil &&
   self.numTxt.text != nil)
{

    NSLog(@"%@ debug ",**self.firstNameTxt.text**); // just for checking for debugging.

} else {
    self.alarmLb.text = @"!fill out all of box!";

}

[self.view endEditing: YES];
}
```

However, the result i'm getting is that even if i leave all empty and press button it goes into if statement and printout ONLY debug without self.firstNametxt.txt displaying..

**Question** : even if i left them empty, why it still pass the if condition which i assume it should be nil.. And not displaying **self.fistNametxt.txt** but display debug string.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: `[xXx isEqualToString:@""]` or `[xxx length] == 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving the text empty does not make it `nil` - you get an empty `NSString`, i.e. a `@""`.

Change the code to check the length to be non-zero, like this:

```
if (self.firstNameTxt.text.length != 0 &&
   self.lastNameTxt.text.length != 0 &&
   self.numTxt.text.length != 0) {
    ...
}
```

Note that since invoking methods on `nil` objects in Objective-C is allowed, checking `length` for zero effectively covers both the situation when a string is `nil` and when the string is empty.

Comment: @dasblickenlight "invoking methods on nil objects" means that text string should be nil..? if not, what it's implying...sir?

Comment: @denis_choe My last note is a general comment on the `str.length` construct - all I wanted to say that it works on `nil` objects as well, so in a situation when `NSString *` object comes from some source where it can be `nil`, you can use `length` without a `nil` check. In your code `text` is never `nil`, but there will be situations when you need to check a string that could be `nil` or empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([self.firstNameTxt.text length] != 0 && [self.lastNameTxt.text length] != 0 && [self.numTxt.text length] != 0)
{
//your code
}
```